# I want to calculate average and store the value in a new column

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to calculate the average on the basis of 2 columns and want t save the value in a new column.Moreover i want to create the column average as it is not already available.

```
UPDATE SCORE
 SET Average=
'SET @v1 := (SELECT sum(runs) FROM `score`),
SET @v2 := (SELECT count(inning) FROM `score` WHERE inning = 'out'),
 SELECT @v1/@v2'
```

[image: here is my table]

Comment: Computed columns potentially have a penalty, in that they either have to updated as new data comes in, or left as they are to become stale data.  Are you sure you want to add a new column here?

Comment: i can also insert in a new table

Comment: can u guide me what will be the query in this case...thanks.

Comment: I don't see the point in dedicating an entire column either in your current table or in a new one to just store a single point of data.  Your current code looks fine to me, and I don't see a problem with it.

Comment: it gives a syntax error when i run it

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'out'),
SELECT @v1/@v2'' at line 3

Comment: You have to run the set and select statements separately, or do not use set, initialise your variables in your select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @TimBiegeleisen has pointed out, usually it is not the best idea to store calculated values, use a query (or view) to dynamically calculate such values.

In this particular example I would not store the calculated values either, since it is based on a summary, so you can't even associate the data with any of the records.

I do not know why you would like to do this in a prepared statement, so I'll give you just plain sql solution, which you can execute as a prepared statement. You do not have to use separate `SET` statements to assign values to your session variables, you can do them in a single `select`. I use a subquery to make absolutely sure that the sum and count are executed before the average calculation. I use conditional counting to avoid another subquery:

```
select sum_runs/count_outs as average
from (select sum(runs) as sum_runs,
             count(if(inning='out',1,null)) as count_outs,
      from `score`) as t
```